# If x,y,z are unequal and if $x+y+z=1$, the expression ${(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\over (1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}$ is greater than(integer)?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, quadratics

If $x, y, z$ are unequal and if $x+y+z=1$, the expression $${(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\over (1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}$$ is greater than (integer)?

I thought of doing this question by the inequality approach like AM, GM, HM, Cauchy-Swartz etc and just got to $(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\ge8(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$ but I am not able to relate it to $(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$.
And is there any more method you can suggest for this question or likewise types?

Comment: In both title and body you say "If x,y,x are unequal...". I think you mean $If x,y,z are unequal...".  Also "is greater than (integer)" but which integer do you mean?

Comment: Yes, thanks. The integer is the number we have to find…

Comment: One more question: are you assuming $x,y,z$ are positive, or maybe at least non-negative?

Comment: The tag [algebra-precalculus] instead of [linear-algebra], unless the solution itself uses linear algebra.

Comment: Yes, in order for the inequalities to work i assumed x,y,z to be +ve

Comment: Using Lagrange Multipliers, on non-negative reals, this expression has the global minimum $8$ at $(\frac13, \frac13, \frac13).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution assumes that the terms are non-negative. It doesn't require that the terms are distinct.

With $ x = y = z = 1/3$, we guess that the answer is 8. Let's verify it.

We normalize the inequality by replacing $ 1 = x+y+z$. WTS

$$ ( 2x+y+z)(2y+z+y)(2z+x+y) \geq 8 (x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$$

Can you prove this by applying AM-GM on each term of the product on the LHS?

> $2x + y + z = (x+y) + (x+z) \geq 2 \sqrt{ (x+y)(x+z) }$.
>  We have analogous inequalities for the other terms.
>  Multiply them together, and we get the inequality.